# Share with Facebook without SLCompose or any kind of dialogue

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

```
import Foundation
class FacebookShareService {
    private var shareImage : UIImage!
    private var shareDescription : String?

    init(image : UIImage, description : String?) {
        self.shareImage = image
        self.shareDescription = description
    }

    func start() {
        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil && FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions.contains("publish_actions"){
            self.startShareToFacebook()
        } else {
            getPublishPermission({ (error) -> () in
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error!!!", message: error.domain, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Close")
                alert.show()
            }, success: { () -> () in
                self.startShareToFacebook()
            })
        }
    }

    private func startShareToFacebook() {
        let dict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        if let des = self.shareDescription
        {
            dict.setValue(des, forKey: "caption")

        }
        dict.setValue(self.shareImage, forKey: "source")
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: dict as [NSObject : AnyObject], HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler { (conn : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, response : AnyObject!, error :NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Can't use graphApi me/photos")
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error!!!", message: error.domain, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Close")
                alert.show()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "", message: "Successful!!!", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Close")
                alert.show()
            }
        }
    }

    private func getPublishPermission(fail : (error : NSError)->(),success:()->()) {
        let loginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Native
        loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"], handler: { (loginResult:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error :NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Can't login with permission public_action")
                fail(error: error)
            } else {
                if let result = loginResult {
                    if loginResult.isCancelled {
                        print("Can not get permisson")
                        fail(error: NSError(domain: "Can not get permisson", code: 100000, userInfo: nil))
                    } else {
                        if let permissions = loginResult.grantedPermissions {
                            if permissions.contains("publish_actions") {
                                success()
                            } else {
                                print("Publish actions is not allowed")
                                let error : NSError = NSError(domain: "Publish actions is not allowed", code: 1000, userInfo: nil)
                                fail(error : error)
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Publish actions is not allowed")
                            let error : NSError = NSError(domain: "Publish actions is not allowed", code: 1000, userInfo: nil)
                            fail(error : error)
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    print("Can not get permisson")
                    fail(error: NSError(domain: "Can not get permisson", code: 100000, userInfo: nil))
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

above code is not working any kind of solution or any kind of ready made source is needed.in this code they are using old SDK and not compatible with new sdk. i am using latest ios SDK.Eagerly waiting for someone's help.

Answer (score 0):

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
        login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
        [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]  handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult result, NSError error) {
            if (error){

            } else if (result.isCancelled){

            } else{
                if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]){
                    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){
                        [self funcGetUserFBInfo];
                    }
                }
            }
        }];
```

For sharing

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
                content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.indianic.com/"];
                [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
                UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
                pasteboard.string = @"“Love only grows by sharing. You can only have more for yourself by giving it away to others”";
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for responce,my question is "Share with Facebook without SLCompose or any kind of dialogue"